# BeautifulSoup AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to try and scrape the following:

```
[<ol class="player-profiles-list">
<li>
<a href="/player-profiles/player-1/">
<img alt="" height="64" src="/images/players/small/default.png" 
width="42"/>
<span>
                                                        player 1                                                    
      </span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/player-profiles/player-2/">
<img alt="" height="64" src="/images/players/small/default.png" 
width="42"/>
<span>
                                                         player 2                                                    
      </span>
</a>
</li>
```

I want to put each of the href (there are more than 2 players) into a dictionary so that I can then loop through adding each of them to a root url. However I'm getting the following error:

'AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
playerList = soup.findAll('ol', {'class' : 'player-profiles-list'}) 
playerDict = {}    

for player in playerList.findAll('a'):
    playerDict[player.text] = player['href']
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a single `<ol class="player-profiles-list"...>` tag or multiple? I think you wanted to use `soup.find('ol', {'class' : 'player-profiles-list'})` instead of `findAll()`. You can't use `BeautifulSoup` methods like `findAll()` on a `list`.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Thank you. There is only a single <ol class="player-profiles-list"...>  tag as you mentioned. Using find() instead of findAll(), the code now runs but doesn't return the desired outcome. I do not understand why I cannot use findAll() on a list however as I'm using the same code as in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4no8cNmCDE) at 7:40 and it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure about the error, but here is a one liner that I used a ways back to strip a page for hrefs. I used a list instead of a dictionary though. I adjusted it a bit to fit your code. Hope this helps!

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
players = soup.find('ol', attrs={'class': 'player-profiles-list'})
links = [a['href'] for a in players.find_all('a', href=True) if a.text.strip()]
```

@Keyur is exactly right about the error! Glad I came back and learned what was wrong.